# Ubuntu 12.10 WiFi Problems

Tags: wireless, 12.10, realtek

I have a 32 bit machine running Ubuntu 12.10 with WiFi on it.
I have a WPA2 network at home, but if I leave the USB Adapter plugged in while it boots, it infinitely keeps asking for the network password but never connects.

If I plug it in after boot, it will connect but then I can't access ANYTHING on the LAN or Internet because "the DNS servers are unreachable". Now, if I leave the computer on a while, I get lucky sometimes and it MAGICALLY decides to connect for a little bit, lock the machine though and the Internet's gone again.

The weirdest thing, is when I am connected but can't get to the  internet, I do a netstat or ifconfig wlan0, I do have an IP address and everything.

It says I'm connected but its not.

I have a Realtek RTL8188CU USB adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drivers for the USB dongles are sometimes a pain. Realtek's web site can help somewhat but not all adapters will work with the latest kernel without some massaging. So, here is the web site for the newest drivers [REALTEK](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=48&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#RTL8188CUS)

after which you will need to blacklist a file. You want to `edit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

Go to the end of the file and add the line:

```
blacklist rtl8192cu
```

Use [this guide](http://www.r-statistics.com/2011/11/edimax-ew-7811un-usb-wireless-connecting-to-a-network-on-ubuntu-11-10/) as a resource